# Understanding ON ERROR in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to modify a vbscript and convert it to Powershell as instructed. I have a block of code on my function SearchAD with On Error.

```
on error resume next
Set objRS = command.execute

SearchAD = objRS.RecordCount
on error goto 0
```

My question would be is what part of the code can trigger RESUME Next and what part is for GOTO 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In VBScript there are two error states (three in other VBs).

```
On Error Goto 0
```

vbscript handles errors. Your program crashes on errors.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

VBScript sets the err object but doesn't raise an error. You are required to put after every line that may raise an error

```
If err.number <> 0 then 
    FreakoutAndFixTheError
    err.clear
    wscript.quit 'if you can't fix
End If
```

In VB6 and VBA there is also

```
On Error Goto LineNumber (or a label)
```

Comment: It's the other way around. `On Error Resume Next` _en_ables error handling (meaning the script does **not** crash on error), `On Error Goto 0` _dis_ables it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, `On Error Resume Next` disables error reporting. And `On Error GoTo 0` restores it. It's often used when a programmer *expects* an error to occur but doesn't want that error to go unhandled and halt their script. For example:

```
' This statement will cause VBScript to throw an error and halt.
i = 1 / 0

' Instead, let us handle the error and decide if its important...
On Error Resume Next    ' Turn off error reporting
i = 1 / 0

' Now, we can test the Err object to see if any errors were thrown...
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ' Success. No error occurred.
ElseIf Err.Number = 11 Then
    ' Error #11 is 'Division by zero'. Do we want to allow it?
End If

' We're through the risky section. Restore error reporting.
On Error GoTo 0
```

Now time for a soap box rant. Don't use it. There are almost always better ways than using `On Error Resume Next`. Assert variable values. Check your array bounds before trying to access array elements. Do QA testing. Validate user input. Be a good programmer and cover all your angles. Don't just close your eyes to any errors and assume everything is going to work. It's abused all too often by VB beginners and, unfortunately, even some of the experts! (end rant)

Comment: Your rant shows misunderstanding. Firstly every real program should have on error resume next - and the programmer should test for errors. I don't know if you disagree with that, I don't think so. **SECONDLY** Vbscript is often used as a batch type language. In batch one usually wants the thing to continue on errors. You want 99% of your file processed if that's all that can be done. You don't want 10% done because someone opened LeaveRoster.doc.

Comment: @phd443322 We're going to have to disagree, it seems. There's nothing preventing a programmer from anticipating errors and testing for them without using `On Error`. More times than not, errors aren't even tested, as in the OP's example. Many (if not most) of the issues on this very site are caused because `On Error Resume Next` was used in a local or worse, global, scope. _"I'm not getting an error. It just doesn't work."_ As for the idea that VBS is a "batch" language (which I also disagree with), I don't want my script continuing on as if nothing happened just so it "completes".

Comment: You misunderstand my comments. Your criticism on misuse of `on error resume next` are correct. However programming practise is to try and handle errors. The languages are designed with this in mind. Checking, most likely, would increase execution time. Your approach would pay off if failures were very likely. But that is rarely the case.

Comment: @phd443322 I agree with much of what you're saying. Handling errors is a necessity, which means `On Error Resume Next` is a necessity. I suppose instead of saying _"Don't use it."_, I should have said, _"Use it correctly!"_. Because I've seen way too many examples of it being used carelessly. Like in my example above, I've seen people use it to hide divide-by-zero errors -- not to _test_ for the error, but to hide it. Instead, they could have just asserted that the divisor <> 0.

Comment: The programmer should anticipate if a zero is possible in normal operastion. If so they should validate. For abnormal operation, where zero is not expected, it should be try - except (in modern lingo). Also the point vbs is often used as a batch file, `on error resume next` has utility. I want as many as my docs as possible backed up, for example.

Comment: My real point is people should be trained into handling errors. Users delete files. Programs should recreate them if possible.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the VB6 (more depth than vbscript's) help on it. VBA is the core language of VB6.

**Visual Basic for Applications Reference**

On Error Statement

Enables an error-handling routine and specifies the location of the routine within a procedure; can also be used to disable an error-handling routine.

Syntax

```
On Error GoTo line 

On Error Resume Next

On Error GoTo 0
```

The On Error statement syntax can have any of the following forms:

Statement Description

`On Error GoTo line`
Enables the error-handling routine that starts at line specified in the required line argument. The line argument is any line label or line number. If a run-time error occurs, control branches to line, making the error handler active. The specified line must be in the same procedure as the On Error statement; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

`On Error Resume Next` 
Specifies that when a run-time error occurs, control goes to the statement immediately following the statement where the error occurred where execution continues. Use this form rather than On Error GoTo when accessing objects.

`On Error GoTo 0` 
Disables any enabled error handler in the current procedure.

Remarks

If you don't use an On Error statement, any run-time error that occurs is fatal; that is, an error message is displayed and execution stops.

An "enabled" error handler is one that is turned on by an On Error statement; an "active" error handler is an enabled handler that is in the process of handling an error. If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler can't handle the error. Control returns to the calling procedure. If the calling procedure has an enabled error handler, it is activated to handle the error. If the calling procedure's error handler is also active, control passes back through previous calling procedures until an enabled, but inactive, error handler is found. If no inactive, enabled error handler is found, the error is fatal at the point at which it actually occurred. Each time the error handler passes control back to a calling procedure, that procedure becomes the current procedure. Once an error is handled by an error handler in any procedure, execution resumes in the current procedure at the point designated by the Resume statement.

Note   An error-handling routine is not a Sub procedure or Function procedure. It is a section of code marked by a line label or line number.

Error-handling routines rely on the value in the Number property of the Err object to determine the cause of the error. The error-handling routine should test or save relevant property values in the Err object before any other error can occur or before a procedure that might cause an error is called. The property values in the Err object reflect only the most recent error. The error message associated with Err.Number is contained in Err.Description.

On Error Resume Next causes execution to continue with the statement immediately following the statement that caused the run-time error, or with the statement immediately following the most recent call out of the procedure containing the On Error Resume Next statement. This statement allows execution to continue despite a run-time error. You can place the error-handling routine where the error would occur, rather than transferring control to another location within the procedure. An On Error Resume Next statement becomes inactive when another procedure is called, so you should execute an On Error Resume Next statement in each called routine if you want inline error handling within that routine.

Note   The On Error Resume Next construct may be preferable to On Error GoTo when handling errors generated during access to other objects. Checking Err after each interaction with an object removes ambiguity about which object was accessed by the code. You can be sure which object placed the error code in Err.Number, as well as which object originally generated the error (the object specified in Err.Source).

On Error GoTo 0 disables error handling in the current procedure. It doesn't specify line 0 as the start of the error-handling code, even if the procedure contains a line numbered 0. Without an On Error GoTo 0 statement, an error handler is automatically disabled when a procedure is exited.

To prevent error-handling code from running when no error has occurred, place an Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement immediately before the error-handling routine, as in the following fragment:

```
Sub InitializeMatrix(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   . . .
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   . . .
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

Here, the error-handling code follows the Exit Sub statement and precedes the End Sub statement to separate it from the procedure flow. Error-handling code can be placed anywhere in a procedure.

Untrapped errors in objects are returned to the controlling application when the object is running as an executable file. Within the development environment, untrapped errors are only returned to the controlling application if the proper options are set. See your host application's documentation for a description of which options should be set during debugging, how to set them, and whether the host can create classes.

If you create an object that accesses other objects, you should try to handle errors passed back from them unhandled. If you cannot handle such errors, map the error code in Err.Number to one of your own errors, and then pass them back to the caller of your object. You should specify your error by adding your error code to the vbObjectError constant. For example, if your error code is 1052, assign it as follows:

```
Err.Number = vbObjectError + 1052
```

Note   System errors during calls to Windows dynamic-link libraries (DLL) do not raise exceptions and cannot be trapped with Visual Basic error trapping. When calling DLL functions, you should check each return value for success or failure (according to the API specifications), and in the event of a failure, check the value in the Err object's LastDLLError property.

---

Send feedback to MSDN.Look here for MSDN Online resources.

Comment: VBScript does not support `On Error Goto label`, so half of this simply doesn't apply.

Comment: Only 1/5th doesn't apply. The reast of it is the best documentation that exists.

Comment: vbscript is a subset of vba is a subset of vb6

Comment: @adolfgarlic vbscript isn't a subset of vba - they are both different subsets of VB